# Visual Foxpro. Insert data from grid to DB

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a grid. How to insert values to database when I edit grid data?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as keyboard shortcut of Ctrl+Y, while the grid has focus... Make sure the property of the grid is set for "AllowAddNew" = true.

Otherwise, if you are planning from doing it from a button on the form, just select the work area and add blank record.  The grid will recognize it immediately

```
select YourTable
append blank
Thisform.YourGrid.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Much will depend on EXACTLY what you are doing but I will make the following assumptions:

1. The grid is an object on a form
2. That you have opened the appropriate table in the data environment

and that this is ALL you have done?

If this is the case then by default any data already in the table will be displayed and will be editable.

then either add a button as suggested above to insert new records or play around with the

ON KEY LABEL Command (see help file)